# Angular 2 - One component trigger refresh of another component on the page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-components

I have a component **ComponentA** that **displays a list of elements**. This list is inited during `ngOnInit`.

I have another component **ComponentB** providing controls that might influence the list of elements shown in ComponentA. E.G. an element may be added.

I need a way to **trigger a reinit of ComponentA.**

Does someone have an idea?

---

**Details**

**A** is a HeaderBar with a menu that shows the list of "savedSearchs"

```
@Component({
  selector: 'header-bar',
  templateUrl: 'app/headerBar/headerBar.html'
})
export class HeaderBarComponent implements OnInit{
  ...
  ngOnInit() {
    // init list of savedSearches
    ...
  }
}
```

**B** is a SearchComponent with the possibility to save searches

```
@Component({
  selector: 'search',
  templateUrl: 'app/search/search.html'
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Use a service with an observable? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: ComponentA is using a service returning an Observable of List of Elements. But after returning the list during ngOnInit it is done. (It is an http-get)

Comment: You create your own observable, so you ca notify component A when component B does something. Just read the docs they are quite explanatory

Comment: A, i got you... Should have read your link first. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14):

You need to provide component, and inject it inside constructor of component where you need to call ngOnInit of other component like I did.

Plunker Demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/M0d65wHjfg4KfwaQ5mPM?p=preview

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
       <comp-one></comp-one>
       <comp-two></comp-two>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor( ) {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}

// ComponentOne with ngOnInit

@Component({
  selector: 'comp-one',
  template: `<h2>ComponentOne</h2>`,
})
export class ComponentOne implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(): void {
    alert("ComponentOne ngOnInit Called")
  }

}

// Added provider of ComponentOne here and injected inside constructor the on button click call ngOnInit of ComponentOne from this component
@Component({
  providers:[ComponentOne],
  selector: 'comp-two',
  template: ` Component Two: <button (click)="callMe()">Call Init of ComponentOne</button>`,
})
export class ComponentTwo implements OnInit {

   constructor(private comp: ComponentOne ) {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
  public callMe(compName: any): void {
    this.comp.ngOnInit();
  }


}
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, ComponentOne, ComponentTwo ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Calling `ngOnInit` is a patch. You can use `BehaviourSubject`. It is Observer and Observable, both. [Refer this link](https://namitamalik.github.io/Realtime-Update-in-Angular2/)

Comment: Hi Rohan remember ? Just saw your answer it helped :)

Comment: @AnandKadhi: Hi Mate, how is it going, glad that it helped you :)